# Auto decrement T-SQL ID when deleting records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In one of our apps, we read in data from a file and expand it into several tables.  If any part of the file is corrupt, we halt the read, and delete whatever data got inserted.

The issue, here, is that we have an auto-increment ID on one of the import tables, and when we remove a problem file, the ID continues from its post-import value, rather than its pre-import value.

In other words...

- ID starts at 50.
- Insert 100 records, max ID is now 150.
- Delete 100 records, max ID is still 150.
- Insert 50 records, ID is 200.

We've "lost" the range of 100 records. Is there an "auto decrement" equivalent to go with the auto increment?

Comment: Use a Transaction and call [`TRANSACTON ROLLBACK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299.aspx) if necessary.

Comment: Why is this a problem? Auto-increment ids are designed so that it's okay to have gaps.

Comment: You can also reseed the IDENT number `DBCC CHECKIDENT`

Comment: @TimSchmelter wouldn't make any difference if he is deleting existing records

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you've lost?  Do you have a specific business requirement that gives meaning to those id's?  If not, then what's the problem?

Comment: @tim - while it would work, transactions sometimes cause performance problems for bulk imports.

Comment: You are not using Identities as they were designed.

Comment: The concern is that those "wasted" IDs may have been useful in that there's an eventual max int limit, but it appears that attempting to get them back may be going against the design of the auto-increment ID type.  Mea culpa; all of the apps I've worked on, historically, have used IDs generated by business logic.  Looks like I've got plenty more to learn. :-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Inserting into a identity column even within a transaction that gets rolled back will burn that ID. Otherwise it would make multiple open transactions very tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autonumbers shouldn't be that meaningful to you.  Their guarantee is they provide uniqueness nothing more.  You can still reseed if you are using sql server `DBCC CHECKIDENT`.

```
Checks the current identity value for the specified table and, if it is needed, changes the identity value. You can also use DBCC CHECKIDENT to manually set a new seed value for the identity column.
```

From BOL:
The following example forces the current identity value in the Employee table in the AdventureWorks database to a value of 30.

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('HumanResources.Employee', RESEED, 30);
GO
```

I am not recommending this but just pointing it out.  `DBCC CHECKIDENT` can throw an error if you try to reseed to a value that is already being used, in that case you'd have to have logic if you were relying upon such a task.

I question the thought process of what makes these numbers so important?  It sounds like you want one additional field called `LineNumber` that is incremented or decremented, etc.  But even in this case you have to handle the rows that come after the deleted record.  So if you have 50 rows and you delete row 25 you have to renumber anything greater then 25:

```
UPDATE 
       MyTable 
SET LineItemNumber = LineItemNumber - 1 
WHERE 
       LineItemNumber > @LineItemNumberToBeDeleted
```

Comment: Will the increment "fill in" gaps as it goes, or will we hit the max value for int before we actually insert that many records?

Comment: @IVRAvenger: with a type `INT`, starting at 1, you get **over 2 billion** possible rows; that should be sufficient for the vast majority of cases. With `BIGINT`, you get roughly **922 quadrillion** (922 with 15 zeros - 922'000 billions) - enough for you?? If you use an `INT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert a row every second, you need 66.5 **years** before you hit the 2 billion limit .... If you use a `BIGINT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert one thousand rows every second, you need a mind-boggling **292 million years** before you hit the 922 quadrillion limit ....

Comment: @JonH IDENTITY in MSSQL - by itself - does not "provide uniqueness". As you mentioned yourself, you can force specific values into the column using `DBCC CHECKIDENT` or `IDENTITY_INSERT`; if you require uniqueness then you need to add a `UNIQUE` constraint or `PRIMARY KEY`. Implementing sequences with no gaps is actually quite difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Auto decrementing on delete sounds like a bad idea.  If done incorrectly, you can start injecting much bigger bugs into your code.  If the IDs are a big deal, try giving it a batch number, and an incremented id for every item in the batch.  You could also use guids, though they're not sequential.

Answer (score 2):

You can reseed the AutoIncrement ID by doing:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT
(
  tablename

  [, [NORESEED | RESEED [, newreseedvalue]]]
)
```

However I would not recommend this as a best practice.  Your query should be atomic (It commits and updates the table or Rollsback if it fails (leaving the ID untouched).  To implement an atomic query you could use a `TRANSACTION`.

```
BEGIN TRY
   BEGIN TRANSACTION @TranName;

     -- Your database logic here

    COMMIT TRANSACTION @TranName;

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

   ROLLBACK TRAN @TranName;

END CATCH

GO
```

Sources:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/how-do-i-reseed-a-sql-server-identity-column/406

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, a best practice for this portion of an ETL (Extract Transform Load) process is to perform the bulk load in more than one step:

1. Load data from file(s) into empty "loading" or "staging" table(s) which exist just for this purpose. This detects file-level corruption.
2. Check data for referential integrity and other validations. This detects data-level errors.
3. Insert only valid data into the "real" tables. This avoids unnecessary deletes and avoids wasting auto increment values.
4. Log or report data which failed the import checks.
5. Immediately before the next run of this process, truncate the "loading" tables.